# Javascript - Store pdf in a variable

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, web-sql

I'm trying to generate a pdf from html and then print the pdf. And besides printing, I also want to store the pdf file in a variable.

This is an app that is supposed to work offline (it will be a mobile app), and when I connect to the server, I can send all the files that I generated. So I'd like to in some way store the pdf file in a variable (so that I can store in websql).

Currently I was printing the document like this

```
var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
printWindow.document.write("<html><head></head><body>");
printWindow.document.write("content here");
printWindow.document.write("</body></html>");
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.print();
```

I'm successfully printing the document, but I can't save it in websql or in a variable so that I can later save in websql.

But I'm still open to any suggestions, my only restriction is that it must work offline (I can download the .js to work with it).

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with PDFs or content, so we can't answer your question (beyond "use the `=` operator").

Comment: I'm printing the content and I want to print also to a .pdf file, and store that in a variable. My code right now is only printing the document, and I'm asking how to also print the document to pdf and store it in websql.

Comment: The browser will not do that for you.

Comment: Well, I used the jsPDF library and with that I can create a pdf and download it locally, and I did it in the browser, so the browser can do that.

What I don't want is it to download. So I know that it can create .pdf but I want it in a variable and not downloadable

Comment: That's your code doing that, not the browser itself.  jsPDF can give you a variable.

Comment: http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#output